MI PUBLICACION CON LA API DE FACEBOOK NO APARECE EN EL FEED
estoy intentando usar la api de facebook para hacer publicaciones en una pagina de facebook, me funciona pero cuando quiero ver la publicacion desde el perfil de otra persona no aparece en el apartado de publicaciones, solo cuando entro a la seccion de fotos es que se puede visualizar; tambien intento compartirla desde el perfil externo para validar si se puede ver en los compartidos y tampoco aparece, es como si no existiera la publicacion.
ya he intentado de todo y lo unico que se me ocurre es que sea temas de permisos de la app en meta porque tengo todos los permisos necesarios a la hora de generar el token.
si alguno tiene una idea me ayudaria mucho, por favor.
Este es el codigo:
$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => $app_id,
    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v21.0',
    // 'published' => 'false',
]);

$data = [
    'message' => $message,
    'url' => $ruta_imagen,
];


try {
    $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, $token_acces);

    echo 'publicacion subida con exito: ' . $response->getGraphNode()['id'];
} catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo 'Error en la respuesta de Facebook: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Error en el SDK de Facebook: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

y estos son mis permisos:
manage_fundraisers
read_insights
publish_video
pages_show_list
instagram_basic
instagram_manage_comments
instagram_manage_insights
instagram_content_publish
leads_retrieval
whatsapp_business_management
instagram_manage_messages
page_events
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_ads
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement

